# Winform change connection strings of datasets at runtime without using exe.config

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, connection-string

I checked already many similar posts but couldnt find exactly whyt I need:

Situation:
I am devloping a winform app which has several datasets included, setup via VS(2019) designer.
The corresponding (created by VS) table adapters using one single connection string. For development, I have set this connection string to devserver\sqldevserver.

Now I want to deploy the app and on startup, user will be asked for HIS SQL server to establish local connections.

Questions:
How to change all those connection strings on startup?
Is there a way to set it global?
At which point the datasets will be initialized ? Only when data is requested from server or at startup?

And: I dont want to deal with the exe.config file. All should be done within single .exe app.

Comment: Does the user have to select their SQL server every time the app starts? If not, you will need to save the setting somewhere, and you can't save it in the .exe.

Comment: A connection string is just a string.  You can get it from anywhere, or create one by composing it's parts.  I regularly write little WinForms utilities where I keep the key part of the connection string in a "Most Recently Used" drop down that the user can pick from.  Between runs of the app, I write that list out (and read it back in) from Isolated Storage.

Comment: No, it will usually be stored in a settings file. But if this doesn't exist, I need to get it. But anyhow, its variable and within code I have to handle it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable like 'MyDatabaseConnectionString' and initialise it as required and then specify the connection when you use the Table Adapters, like this

```
Dim dt As New ThisDataTable
Using ta As New MyTableAdapters.ThisTableAdapter
    ta.Connection = New SqlConnection(MyDatabaseConnectionString)
    ta.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

You don't include any code so I have made up TableAdapter and DataTable names, but this should give you an idea how to do it.

```
   Public Sub FillDataSet(ByRef ds As DataSet,)

        For Each t As DataTable In ds.Tables

            Dim adType As Type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetType("TSA." & ds.DataSetName & "TableAdapters." & t.TableName & "TableAdapter")

            'Create Adapter Instance     
            Dim adapter As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(adType)

' Here should be the assignment of the connection like
' adapter.connection = New SqlConnection(MyDatabaseConnectionString) - but not working as the method is not found by compiler

            'Fill the Table   
            adapter.GetType().GetMethod("Fill").Invoke(adapter, New Object() {t})
        Next
  End Sub
```

EDIT:

Werner, Connection is a public property on all TableAdapters.  I think the issue is that you are using an Activator to create your Adapters (I'm not familiar with that) so the compiler just thinks it's an object.  You should still be able to specify Connection= and rely on late binding to resolve it at run time.

```
Dim ta As Object = Nothing
ta.Connection = New SqlConnection(SQLConnString)
```

The above code compiles although it will fail at run time. In your case, at the object is a tableadapter, it should work at run time I think.  Have you tried it?

Comment: The idea sounds promising. But in my example unfortunately not working.
I have a central fill procedure for all DataSets where it would fit perfectly, but the adapter instances vary. Here the code (in VB):

Comment: SqlConnection is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection - assuming you are using SQL.  If not, use the equivalent for whichever DB you are using.

Comment: As your adapter is object, the compiler won't know what it is so can't prompt.  It may be worth casting it to a SqlDataAdapter so Intellisense can help you.

Comment: I tried this already, but it is not a SQL Adapter, its of type DATASETnameTABLEADAPTER.nameTABLEADAPTER. At debugging, I can see its properties. Has Connection, ConnectionString, all what we would need. But the type is created dynamically and I have no idea how to cast ist ..

Comment: Add:
The error message I get (at runtime) is "the public member 'connection' for type 'nameTABLEADAPTER' was not found. Though, with intellisense, I can see it. I tried already to set the member generation in the designer to 'public' but also didnt change behaviour.

Comment: Made my edit before seeing your last comment.  I can't say why that doesn't work as I think it should.  Another option is to use partial classes and extend each of your TableAdapters to expose a method you can call to set the Connection, but that's a bit longwinded of you've a lot of tableadapters.  (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/extend-the-functionality-of-a-tableadapter?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Jon, again thx for your effort to help me !
Yes, I tried, but its not working. At runtime it throws the "member not found" exception. This topic is not new and many people struggle with it. I found a quite old post with well explanation:
https://rajmsdn.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/strongly-typed-dataset-connection-string/
However, this will also not solve my problem. I will have in this projects dozens of this typed TableAdapters and cant code all of them

Comment: Have you seen the very final answer in this post, the one by Graham Lower. Would that help? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4a676ab-83e5-42f5-9b8a-5af2d8792e4e/tableadapters-baseclass

Comment: I am one step further. I can access some of the properties of the adapter instance and change them.:

Dim boxedObject As Object = RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(adapter)
adapter.GetType().GetProperty("ClearBeforeFill").SetValue(boxedObject, False)

But when I try to access (friend) property "Connection", it still tells me - not found ..
Thx for the above link, but syntax was for .net 3.5 and not working for 4.7 anymore

Comment: OK, gone as far as I can now but it does look like that last example with reflection may be the way forward.  I think the internal adapter is prefixed with underscore, so _adapter.  If you can create a wrapper and access the connection property, hopefully that offers a solution but it's not an area I've any expertise in.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can build connectionstring on startup like this:

```
public static string BuildConnectionString(string userid, string password)
{
    var builder = new SQLConnectionStringBuilder(<YourConnectionString>);

    var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(<YourDbProviderName>);
    var providerBuilder = factory.CreateConnectionStringBuilder();

    providerBuilder.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

    if (providerBuilder.ContainsKey("userid"))
        providerBuilder.Remove("userid");

    if (providerBuilder.ContainsKey("password"))
        providerBuilder.Remove("password");

    providerBuilder.Add("userid", userid);
    providerBuilder.Add("password", password);

    return providerBuilder.ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: Thx, the connection string itself is not the problem. Problem is, to assign the connection at runtime to the (variable) TableAdpaters used in the program

Comment: Ok I understand now. The only way that I can imagine you can achieve this is to extend the functionality of TableAdapter and expose a BeforeConnection event and change the connectionstring in that event. This is quite a bit of programming though.

Comment: For two, three adapters, no problems. But as I will have dozens of them ... uff